# R: Turn Months into Quarters

Tags: r, date, character

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
> ex
 # A tibble: 10 × 2
 tenor   delivery_window
 <chr>   <chr>          
 1 month   Nov 22         
 2 quarter Jan 22         
 3 year    Cal 24         
 4 year    Cal 22         
 5 month   Feb 22         
 6 quarter Jan 21         
 7 month   Sep 22         
 8 quarter Jan 21         
 9 month   Jun 21         
10 month   Aug 21
```

And which I want to turn into something like this:

```
> ex
 # A tibble: 10 × 3
 tenor   delivery_window new_tenor
 <chr>   <chr>           <chr>    
 1 month   Nov 22          Nov 22   
 2 quarter Jan 22          Q1 22    
 3 year    Cal 24          Cal 24   
 4 year    Cal 22          Cal 22   
 5 month   Feb 22          Feb 22   
 6 quarter Jan 21          Q1 21    
 7 month   Sep 22          Sep 22   
 8 quarter Jan 21          Q1 21    
 9 month   Jun 21          Jun 21   
10 month   Aug 21          Aug 21
```

That is, if the `tenor` is `quarter`, I want to show only the quarter corresponding to the `delivery window`, not the month. Monthly and Yearly tenors can remain as they are.

Can someone please give me a hint as to how to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

The `new_tenor` should be `Q1 YY` for months from Jan to Mar, `Q2 YY` for months from `Apr YY` to `Jun YY`, `Q3 YY` for months from `Jul YY` to `Sep YY`, and `Q4 YY` for months from `Oct YY` to `Dec YY`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can convert to `yearqtr` with `as.yearqtr` (from `zoo`), and use `case_when` to replace the elements in 'delivery_window' with the converted value

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(zoo)
ex <- ex %>%
        mutate(new_tenor = case_when(tenor == 'quarter' 
   ~ str_replace(as.yearqtr(paste('1', delivery_window), 
       '%d %b %Y'), "(\\d+) (\\w+)", "\\2 \\1")
, TRUE ~ delivery_window))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, the `new_tenor` can be any quarter of the year, depending on the month. Sorry I didn't make myself clear, I will edit my question.